# What I have to write in "table" of CombiTable1D1 when data are stored in a txtFile?

Tags: openmodelica

Sorry for my English. I hope to be clear.

I've created a `txtFile`, named `theta-s.txt`, in which `tab1` has many float values. In particular it has 18001 rows and 2 columns. I think that file structure is right to be read by `combitable` block.

I don't know what I have to write in "Table" in `CombiTable1D1` parameters for recalling "tab1" data. Default is `fill(0.0, 0, 2)` but it's not good for me.

Can you help me please?
Thanks

Alessandro

Comment: please give us the code you tried and/or the error message or undesired results you obtained and/or the results you expected.

Comment: Hello. I want to describe you my parameters set of combitable1D. Under Table data definition section I've wrote as follows : TableOnFile-->true, table-->loadResource("C:/Users/Yamaha R6/Desktop/FileOpenModelica/combitable1.txt"), tableName-->tab1, fileName-->combitable1. When I simulate the model the following error occurs : [1] 15:51:20 Translation Errore
Class loadResource not found in scope Prova (looking for a function or record). What can I do? Thank you very much

Comment: Alessandro, we are not answering your questions for your sake only. We are building a knowledge base here. Would you please edit your question so that future users of this website understand it without reading all comments?

Answer (score 0):

The [documentation](https://build.openmodelica.org/Documentation/Modelica.Blocks.Sources.CombiTimeTable.html) states:

> The table matrix can be defined in the following ways:
>
> 1. Explicitly supplied as parameter matrix "table", and the other
>      parameters have the following values:    tableName is "NoName" or has
>      only blanks,    fileName  is "NoName" or has only blanks.
> 2. Read from a
>      file "fileName" where the matrix is stored as "tableName".
> 3. (Not really working in OpenModelica)

So when reading from a file, like you want to do, the contents of the `table` variable does not matter and it's best to keep it as 0-length in order to keep the model as simple as possible.